# hide first span and label in a div with css

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a js program that I don't know how to edit.  It's outputting redundant code for my need So I'm wondering if there is a way to hide the 1st label and 1st span of it's output within a specific div.  Here is the output

```
<div class="rnTotalBox">
    <label></label>  //hide this 
    <span class="price rn-price "> //hide this
        <span class="amount">$0.00</span> //hide this
    </span> //hide this
    <label>Final Total</label><span class="price rn-price ">
        <span class="amount">$0.00</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I thought I could use css like this:

```
.rnTotalBox label:first-child {
    display:none;
}
.rnTotalBox span:first-child {
    display:none;
}
```

but they hide everything no matter what.  Is there a way to hide the first label and the first span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `label:first-of-type` selector!

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/